# How to run a loop on a bunch of Android buttons that need to control their neighbors?

Tags: java, android

I have a list of text inputs that each contain numbers.  To the left of each is a button that says " - " to the right one that says " + ".

So, it looks like this:

```
[ - ] [ 1111 ] [ + ]
[ - ] [ 1112 ] [ + ]
[ - ] [ 1113 ] [ + ]
etc...
```

I want each [-] to alter the value of the field next to it, reducing it by 1, and each [+] to increment the value of the field left of it.

Is there a way that I can write a generic listener that would, upon instantiation, take as a param the id of the text field to be edited?
setOnClickListener only takes a View.OnClickListener as a param, and that can't be given any extra params to hang onto either.  Do I have to extend View.OnClickListener with my own custom listener to do this? Or is there some obvious way to accomplish this task that I'm overlooking?

TIA.

Comment: You said that you have a list of those EditTexts with a button on each right? So the + and - buttons only handler their assigned EditText and not all is that correct?

Comment: Ocatvian, that's the intent yes. The problem is that there's no simple way to associate them, seeing as how their IDs don't really exist in any meaningful way for examination.  I might call it plus0, field0, and minus0, but then it's all translated into code and I can't access them in a "hashy" way.  However, I've gotten around this now by extending the click handler, as I had thought I might have to.  I was hoping someone would come along and say "you CAN get the item's XMLy ID and then examine it as a string and get the number out of it, and then go and access the appropriate text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Please note that this is just an idea I can't test right now due to not being near a PC

So, how about this: the buttons extend the view class, meaning they have a getParent method which will return their parent view. So, think about a listener like this:

```
public void onClick(View v){
TextView count = (TextView) ((v.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.counter));
switch(v.getId()){
case: R.id.incrementButton:
// increase value in count
break;
case R.id.decrementButton:
// decrease value in count
break;
}
}
```

No need for additional classes or hacky id management, all in a simple flexible OnClickListener.

Comment: Forgot to mention, this assumes that the (-), (+) and the counter are all contained in a View such as a LinearLayout so that the findViewById only takes those in a row as candidates.

Comment: yes... that could also work.  Not sure about using counter id, but if this is all being build dynamically that would not be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the [`onClick`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html#onClick%28android.view.View%29) event of the [`OnClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) only takes a single [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) as an argument. However, both the [`Button`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) and [`EditText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) classes are descendants of the `View` class, so you can use this one parameter to check which button triggered the event. The code below provides a simple example:

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (v == bt1Decrement)
        {
            // Decrement field 1
        }
        else if (v == bt1Increment)
        {
            // Increment field 1
        }
        // else if... continue to check for the rest of the buttons
    }
};
```

You can then use this single listener for all your buttons. The above code could probably be done in a much more elegant way (e.g. keep references to the buttons in some array structure you could loop over), but it illustrates the point :)

Comment: thanks. I thought of this approach, but this, unfortunately, requires that I consider every possible item in my list (and there are N number of them, depending on other factors).   So, what I have done is I have created my own listener which implements View.onClickListener and to which I pass all the necessary info in a loop for each set of buttons and inputs.  I guess you could call it more "elegant", it's certainly more verbose! :)

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: Ok, I see. I looked a bit around, and found something about `set/getInputExtras` and `android:editorExtras` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setInputExtras%28int%29). I haven't tried this myself, but is this perhaps something that can be useful for you?

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like extending View.OnClickListener with my own custom listener is the most straight forward approach. I generate a text field dynamically as well as the + and - buttons and pass the custom listener a reference to the text field. It's a bit hacky, but I don't see a more straight forward approach at this time.

EDIT
Leaving this solution up as it also works but like mrPjer's one better (even thought it's not, exactly, what I was hoping for).